# How to calculate time

Tags: sql

I made a table data like below and I want to filter time with category hour -8 and +8.

[image]

I made a query like this but wrong result

```
select resolved_by, count(*) as total,
count (resolution_time > HOUR (resolution_time -8)) as total_target,
count (resolution_time > HOUR (resolution_time +8)) as total_untarget
from all_ticket_closed
where resolved_by = 'Oktadika.Riptono'
group by resolved_by;
```

[image]

For the result, total_target should be 32 and total_untarget 10. how to query it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do not post images of tables. Use `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements pasted as **text** into the post. Tag the DBMS you're using and its version. [Edit] the question to do so. Do not use comments for that.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Also, what data type is `resolution_time`?

Comment: Hi GarethD,
I'm using mysql and data type is time.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you may require CASE expression and SUM function for aggregation

```
SUM (CASE WHEN resolution_time > HOUR THEN (resolution_time -8) ELSE 0 END) as total_target,
SUM (CASE WHEN resolution_time > HOUR THEN (resolution_time +8) ELSE 0 END) as total_untarget
```

Comment: SELECT resolved_by
, COUNT(*) as total
, COUNT(CASE WHEN HOUR(resolution_time) -8 THEN resolution_time END) as total_target,
, COUNT(CASE WHEN HOUR(resolution_time) +8 THEN resolution_time END) as total_untarget
FROM all_ticket_closed
GROUP BY resolved_by;

SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=50816) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' COUNT(CASE WHEN HOUR(resolution_time) +8 THEN resolution_time END) as total_unt' at line 2